# GODADDY EMAIL SERVER | Client-Outlook | Send/Receive all mail including folders to Outlook from GoDaddy

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook, sync, download

`UPDATED-STATEMENT: 20180827@132100 Post created
UPDATED-STATEMENT: 20180828@161300 Helped by LPChip & Steven Fan that POP3 downloads from inbox only & IMAP syncs both inbox/folders. Use IMAP if possible.`

I'm using GoDaddy email server w/ Outlook desktop client. My email works on the webpage and on outlook via POP3 and i'm able to send/receive interchangeably. There is just about one important function that doesn't work *refreshing outlook* and that's to get all mails besides just from inbox only:

1. **How to import *mail-within-folders* from Godaddy server?**

What I mean by mirroring to have both sides appear the same and what ever setup I have in my webpage email has to end up having outlook match it. This includes all mails within inbox and all folders with mail in it form the web sever to outlook. This also means the folder structure has to be created in outlook for it to match.

## SETUP

- Web Mail Server: GoDaddy
- Mail Client: Microsoft Outlook (Office 2016)
- OS: Windows 7 x64 (Pro Edition)

## PROBLEM

- Can't get web mail to outlook to include folder-structures

  - I've invested a lot of time in my current pop3 email how can I fix this?

## SOLUTION

- Use IMAP if possible

  - POP3 is only limited to get from inbox only while IMAP syncs inbox/folders with mail in each folder
  - pop3 (basic): downloads from point a to b and that's it
  - imap (recommended): syncs everything. if there's a directory it'll get synced.
- If you're unable to use IMAP then manually retrieve mail (*tedious way*)

  - move all mail to web mail inbox as-per folder individually and refresh outlook. continue to do this until all your mail is sorted with the same folder structure as the web mail.

Comment: You'll want to configure your mail to use IMAP instead of POP3. That will sync the status and location of emails too, not just download it.

Comment: This is a question & answer site, if you found a solution, please post it as an answer in Stef of including it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 is a download only protocol, and a POP3 account only is capable of downloading from the Inbox folder. If you want all your emails and folder structure to sync with the mail server, then you'll need to configure it as an IMAP account.